# laravel5 ,\Auth::check(),return true,but attempt() return false

Tags: php, laravel

after login,i want add logic before the controller,so i wrote in the middleware .
but,i found when i

```
dd(\Auth::check());  // it returns true;
```

but

```
$eid = \Auth::user()->eid;  //can print the value
$password = \Auth::user()->password; //can print the value, too
dd(\Auth::validate(['eid'=>$eid,'password'=>$password]));  //it returns false
```

the whole code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    dd(\Auth::check());
    $eid = \Auth::user()->eid;
    $password = \Auth::user()->password;
    dd(\Auth::validate(['eid'=>$eid,'password'=>$password]));
    if ($this->auth->guest())
    { // not login
        if ($request->ajax())
        {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: the Users table,is  eid and password two columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Auth::user()->password` is the password hash and it cannot be used in `validate()` function. You can only use the actual plaintext password in `Auth::validate()`

Comment: i want add logic after login,but i can only get the hash password ,how can i get the plaintext password?

Comment: You can get it only when user enters it. There is nowway you can get password fom hash itself